# Where are the unit tests for "native" Java classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing

For "fun" I'm loosely porting a few Java classes to PHP (e.g. [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://code.google.com/p/mrclay/source/browse/trunk/php/java/util/regex/Matcher.php)), so I'd like to be able to run/port the unit tests for these:

- `java.lang.StringBuilder`
- `java.util.regex.Pattern`
- `java.util.regex.Matcher`

Where can I find them? Tests from any semi-recent version would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know whether these are the same as Oracle's JDK proper, but maybe OpenJDK has such tests?

Comment: I wouldn't say "native Java classes", but rather "classes in the Java runtime library"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OpenJDK project offers its source online. The test directory for e.g. `StringBuilder` can be found at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u2/jdk/file/58ad18490a50/test/java/lang/StringBuilder/. Replace the version number with the version you are interested in, and adjust the path accordingly to find the tests for all other classes.

Comment: Wow, would've expected ... higher ... quality ... tests. Still, +1

Comment: +1: StringBuilder is used in a few places and if it were broken it would show up somewhere else.  You only need tests for functionality no other test covers.  The code is basically the same as http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u2/jdk/file/58ad18490a50/test/java/lang/StringBuffer/ so you can use these tests too.