# Where can I find unit tests for Java standard library classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, standard-library

I'm planning on subclassing certain classes in the Java standard library (my immediate use case is extending java.io.File), and I'd like to be able to test that I haven't broken any contracts of the class. I thought there must be some unit tests for the Java standard library classes available under a permissive licence that I can use, however I can't seem to find any.

[This question was asked 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422388/where-can-i-find-unit-tests-for-sun-classes), but no good answer was given.

Comment: And what are those classes you want to subclass exactly? If it is an interface, they are pretty well documented, just make tests to ensure the full contract is obeyed

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492157/where-are-the-unit-tests-for-native-java-classes.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out extending java.io.File was a bad idea, so never mind that.

For the standard collections, guava-tests has some excellent interface contract tests. For example, https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/collect/CompactHashSetTest.java uses [SetTestSuiteBuilder](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/collect/testing/SetTestSuiteBuilder.java) to test that CompactHashSet complies with Set contracts.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/quality/collaborate/testing.html